# Unable to connect to mongodb server. npm ERR! code ENOENT npm ERR! syscall open

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, npm

I am encountering an issue with npm that I haven't been able to resolve, and I would appreciate some guidance. When attempting to run npm commands like npm start in my project directory, I consistently receive the following error:

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /Users/manishavenkatesha/Desktop/Memories_fin/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent Could not read package.json: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/manishavenkatesha/Desktop/Memories_fin/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "mongoose": "^8.0.0",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.1"
  }
}
```

This is my index.js

```
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import cors from 'cors';

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "30mb", extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: "30mb", extended: true}));
app.use(cors());

const { domainToASCII, domainToUnicode } = require('url');
const encoded = domainToASCII('example.com');


const CONNECTION_URL = 'mongodb+srv://manishavenkatesha03:Teal@2020@cluster0.eco0hxf.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority';
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

mongoose.connect(CONNECTION_URL, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true})
    .then(()=> app.listen(PORT,() => console.log('Server running on port: ${PORT}')))
    .catch((error) => console.log(error.message));

mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
```

Checked the existence and permissions of the package.json file.
Verified that I am in the correct project directory when running npm commands.
Cleared the npm cache using npm cache clean -f.
Reinstalled Node.js and npm.
Run npm commands with administrative privileges.